# Sum concerning Catalan triangle and binomials

Tags: summation, binomial-coefficients, factorial, catalan-numbers

I am trying to prove the following relation. For $k \in \mathbb{N},k \geq 2$ and $i=1,\ldots,k-1$
\begin{equation}
{2k-2-i \choose k-1-i}=\sum \limits_{l=0}^{k-1-i} 2^{2l} T(k-2-l,k-1-i-l)-2 \sum \limits_{l=0}^{k-2-i} 2^{2l} T(k-2-l,k-2-i-l)
\end{equation}
where 
\begin{equation}
T(w,u):=\frac{(w+u)!(w-u+1)}{u!(w+1)!}
\end{equation}
are the entries in the [Catalan triangle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan%27s_triangle) for $w \geq 0$ and $ w \geq u \geq 0$ (else T(w,u)=0).

I tried induction over $i$ or use the fact that the 2nd sum is (without the "$2$" factor) the 1st sum evaluated at $i+1$.

Could you please help me?
Thank you.

Edit: If you write the rhs above in terms of factorials, one obtains:
\begin{align*}
\sum \limits_{l=0}^{k-1-i} 2^{2l} \frac{(2k-i-3-2l)! i}{(k-1-i-l)!(k-1-l)!} -2 \sum \limits_{l=0}^{k-2-i} 2^{2l} \frac{(2k-i-4-2l)! (i+1)}{(k-2-i-l)!(k-1-l)!}.
\end{align*}
One can also write $2^{2l}$ in terms of binomial coefficients.
\begin{align*}
&\sum \limits_{l=0}^{k-1-i} \sum \limits_{j=0}^{l} \binom{2l-j}{l-j} 2^{j} \frac{(2k-i-3-2l)! i}{(k-1-i-l)!(k-1-l)!} -2 \sum \limits_{l=0}^{k-2-i} \sum \limits_{j=0}^{l} \binom{2l-j}{l-j} 2^{j}\frac{(2k-i-4-2l)! (i+1)}{(k-2-i-l)!(k-1-l)!}\\
&=\sum \limits_{l=0}^{k-1-i} \sum \limits_{j=0}^{l} \sum \limits_{r=0}^{j} \binom{2l-j}{l-j} \binom{j}{r}  \frac{(2k-i-3-2l)! i}{(k-1-i-l)!(k-1-l)!} -2 \sum \limits_{l=0}^{k-2-i} \sum \limits_{j=0}^{l} \sum \limits_{r=0}^{j}  \binom{2l-j}{l-j} \binom{j}{r}\frac{(2k-i-4-2l)! (i+1)}{(k-2-i-l)!(k-1-l)!}.
\end{align*}
The 1st equation comes from the question "partial sum involving factorials" in this forum and the 2nd one from
\begin{equation}
\sum \limits_{k=0}^{n} \binom{n}{k}=2^{k}.\\
\end{equation}
However I have no clue how to continue.